# need to display in my android app

Tags: android

I need to create a android app which shows pdf files.Normally android doesn't support pdf files.In my app there are three fragments.I need to view separate pdf files on each fragment.what are the libraries available for this

Comment: Adobe reader is available on Android. Android phones now ship with Quickoffice, which supports PDFs very well. Unfortunately, I doubt you can do better than Adobe or Google on this.

Comment: I need to build a app with pdf viewing support.I guess there is no any pdf viewers install in clients phones.what are the ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pdfviewer library.This library is good for viewing pdf on Android platform.
https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library/zipball/master

Comment: This library doesn't provide pinch zoom in facility.It gives a two button to zoom-in and zoom-out.I need pinch zoom add my project?

Comment: try to use mupdf library